# Add language switcher in section where i need

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I want to add the language switcher block along with menus as show in the example. Please see this website http://rafedh.sa . I want to do something like this. Drupal by default does this. But i am not able to move it to top to shown in menu. By default its shown at end of the node.

I am using this theme http://drupal.org/project/danland

Comment: can't you move the block, in the block overview /admin/structure/blocks

Comment: @rémy - i am not using any modules. It comes by default drupal and code is in node.tpl.php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `print render($content['links']);` up, as this outputs the alternative language links (among others).

Comment: There is no such code in my page.tpl.php file..

Comment: this code definitely prints your language buttons .., i bet you didn't clear the cache or somehting

Comment: I did clear cache.... No effect.

Comment: The code you have given is part of node.tpl.php. If i put it at top of page also it will be just above content. I want to print the links at top of the page even before the logo section.I need to write some code in page.tpl.php so that it appears in proper position.

Comment: try $page['content']['links'] in page.tpl.php, or move it up by css position: absolute or fixed

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused.  The "language switcher block" is a block on the blocks page that allows you to switch the language.  You can move it around like any other block; if you don't see it, you will need to install the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

The language link at the end of the node is a link to the translation that can be hidden or shown for your content type by editing the `Manage display` page for the relevant content type.

Comment: "The language link at the end of the node" i want to move this at top of the page, is it possible.?? because language switcher module give list of all lanuagues

Comment: Yes, see remy's answer.

Comment: there is no such code in my page.tpl.php file

Comment: it's in node.tpl.php ;)